# Bootstrap possible explanations for column overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can somebody give me possible explanations for overlapping columns like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MYPk.png) at screen size where they are about to get stacked. My entire code is available here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM4QTOQ319HP

Answer (score 0):

Your source code contains inline style `white-space: nowrap;`
which is responsible for overflow of text and in turn overlapping the text over next column. If you remove that, it will work as expected. Bootstrap wraps the text by default.